# Layout coming over another layout

Tags: android

I am using `RelativeLayout`.

In RelativeLayout,i've a LinearLayout in which i am using `GridView`. The `GridView` is populating at run time . But all the values are not showing.

Under `LinearLayout` there is a `TextView`. I want As the LinearLayout increases the other part below it should move down.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/firstimage"
    tools:context=".SendMessage" >
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="To:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the code where i am setting gridview

ViewGroup layout=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linear);

```
       // gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            gridview=new GridView(getBaseContext());

             String[] items = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "really2", "really3",
                    "really4", "really5", "silly", "list" };
             ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                items);



            gridview.setAdapter(aa);
             layout.addView(gridview);
```

Comment: Provide the layouts and the relevant code please.

Comment: Please post your layout code.

Comment: where should i post tyhe code

Comment: Edit your question and paste the layout and the relevant code there.

Comment: Which Text View You are going to show below linear layout??